# Natural Language Processing using Apache SOLR

Tags: java, solr, nlp

I am working on an application where we use Apache SOLR as an Index Server. A new requirment requires us to implement "Natural Language Processing" on the already indexd products.
Seeking for the suggestion. how should i proceed here. And if there are any Java Frameworks/Library availabel with apache solr to address this issue.

Comment: What kind of NLP do you want to perform? Solr already does some "NLP" for you. There is some basic stuff like stemming that is already built in and you can configure to suit your needs.

Comment: you can take a look at http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/04/04/complete-n00bs-guide-to-enhancing-solrlucene-search-with-mahouts-machine-learning/

Comment: @JosepValls, Thank for your answer. Actually we are looking for NLP on the already indexed data in SOLR, and that to, there are some words which are specific to business domain. And business want to club both "english" and "domain specific" words togather.

Comment: That is a very broad question but just take in mind that the data in SOLR may have already preprocessed (stemmed) which may hinder other NLP processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about using "Natural Language Processing" in solr.

You have not specified what that mean to you.

It could mean: Detection of language and heuristic for stemming

In this case take a look to the documentation:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Detecting+Languages+During+Indexing
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis#LanguageAnalysis-Language-SpecificFactories

It could e.g. also mean using morphology for stemming ( morphological analysis / lemmatization ).
In this case there are open source products like

- http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/ (for english, looks fine)
- https://dev2.dariah.eu/wiki/display/TextGrid/Lemmatizer (for german, looks outdated)

and commerzial products like

- https://www.lingsoft.fi/analysis (XeLDA)
- http://www.iai-sb.de/iai/index.php/findaut.html (FindAUT)

Comment: Thank you so much @karsten for you support. This was very helpful.